# Kubuntu 22.04 kubuntu-driver-manager broken and nvidia driver not running after update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

I'm on the second clean installation of Kubuntu 22.04 and I keep encountering the same problem:

Once the system receives a firmare update, the nvidia driver stops working

```
user@pc:~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Additionally, nvidia-driver-manager becomes unusable as when a different video driver is clicked it throws this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/qt/SoftwarePropertiesQt.py", line 1065, in on_driver_selection_changed
    modules_package_obj = self.apt_cache[modules_package]
TypeError: Expected a string or a pair of strings
```

I'm currently on kernel 6.2.0-1009-lowlatency but the same happens when I switch to a previous kernel. I also managed to switch from 535 to 525 nvidia driver via command line, but unfortunately it doesn't help too.

EDIT: I got the nvidia driver working again by running
`sudo apt -y install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

However the driver manager is still broken.